# How to check for presence of a string in a property

Tags: msbuild

If I have a property

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MyProp>abd;efg;hij;klm</MyProp>
</PropertyGroup>
```

How do I parse `$(MyProp)` to check the presence of `klm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [property functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions) to invoke the string `Contains()` method to check for string occurrences. While some other options using the Items (through an `Include="$(MyProp)"` and checking if an item with the expected identity exists) is also possible, conditions using property functions can be used on any msbuild element, both inside and outside of targets.

Example:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MyProp>abd;efg;hij;klm</MyProp>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Build">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="klm is included!" Condition="$(MyProp.Contains('klm'))" />

    <PropertyGroup>
      <MyProp>;$(MyProp);</MyProp>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Importance="high" Text="exactly klm is included!" Condition="$(MyProp.Contains(';klm;'))" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The second approach - pre- and appending `;` and checking for `;klm;` - makes sure that the string is matched as a whole in the list can deal with `;aklm`.